# How do I return printed output in list format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code compares a nested list of words and returns back whether the two words are anagrams of each other or not

Comment: just append that data to a list

Comment: Just move your if statement into a list comprehension. `for words in nested_anagrams:
    print(["anagrams" if sorted(words[0].lower()) == sorted(words[1].lower()) else "not anagrams"])`

Comment: @KuboMD This will output a lot of one-element lists. I don't think this is what OP wants

Comment: You're right. Slipped my mind that the loop goes inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
print(["anagrams" if sorted(words[0].lower()) == sorted(words[1].lower()) else 
       "not_anagrams" for words in nested_anagrams])
```

Or create a `list` and `append` to it if you think this is not readable:

```
output = []
for words in nested_anagrams:
    if sorted(words[0].lower()) == sorted(words[1].lower()):
        output.append("anagrams")
    else:
        output.append("not_anagrams")
print(output)
```

You can even remove the `if`, but *please* don't do that in production code ;)

```
print([["not_anagrams", "anagrams"][sorted(words[0].lower()) == sorted(words[1].lower())]
       for words in nested_anagrams])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however with the list comprehension method, it gives the desired output but it it returns numerous times e.g     ["anagrams","not_anagrams","not_anagrams",...]["anagrams","not_anagrams","not_anagrams",...]["anagrams","not_anagrams","not_anagrams",...]["anagrams","not_anagrams","not_anagrams",...]  Do you know why this may be?

Comment: @mryoloface You most probably copy-pasted my example into your existing `for` loop which you don't need anymore.